# XMPP server. How to open TLS connection?

Tags: java, firebase, ssl, server, xmpp

I need help with initialization TLS connection to Firebase Cloud Messaging from my XMPP Java server app. I know that FCM do not support STARTTLS extension.
How to do it in the other way?

Answer (score 1):

You are right

> Note that FCM doesn't currently support the STARTTLS extension.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server

Also, is described here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#choose , XMPP is a legacy protocol to interact with FCM server

So it's recommended to switch to [FCM HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages)  which supports HTTPS

Comment: But I need to send upstream messages so I have to use XMPP. But I just realized if I make a connection to Production port, a connection is over TLS.